# Testing a Django Form with a CSV upload

Tags: django, django-forms, django-testing

I have a form that the user upload's a CSV into for data processing. I'm currently trying to test the `form.is_valid()` method. However I am following the Django documentation, and the form is still returning an error that the field requires a value. Any ideas?

**The Documentation**

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/) show the following example -

```
>>> c = Client()
>>> with open('wishlist.doc') as fp:
...     c.post('/customers/wishes/', {'name': 'fred', 'attachment': fp})
```

**The Test**

```
class TestImportCSVForm(TestCase):

    def test_form_valid(self):
        with open('fake.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
            form_data = {
                'csv_file':  csvfile,
            }
            form = ImportCSVForm(data=form_data)
            self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

**The Form**

```
class ImportCSVForm(forms.Form):
    """ Form for uploading CSVs """
    csv_file = forms.FileField(
        label=_("CSV File"),
        help_text=_("Upload a CSV"))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'csv_file',
            HTML("""<hr>"""),
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn btn-primary')
            )
        )
```

**The error when I run the test**

```
(Pdb) form.errors
{'csv_file': ['This field is required.']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass files in to a form with the files kwarg.

class TestImportCSVForm(TestCase):

```
def test_form_valid(self):
    with File(file=tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()) as csvfile:
        csvfile.write(b'test')
        csvfile.flush()
        form_data = {
            'csv_file':  csvfile,
        }
        form = ImportCSVForm(files=form_data)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

Comment: I think you are right, however it is still erring - `{'csv_file': ['No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form.']}`. In manually testing the form, there aren't any issues with the form as it is. Thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I get the same when trying it out. I checked my past form tests including files, and this is how I handled them, with temp files, rather than opening an actual file. Perhaps I had run into the same issue and since I was just checking validity, this worked fine as a unit test. Sorry on the formatting, can't figure out a code block in a comment.

`with File(file=tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()) as f:
    f.write(b'test')
    f.flush()

    form = DocumentationForm(data={'title': 'Test'},
        files={'document_file': f})
        
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())`

Comment: That solved it. If you change your answer, I'll accept it. Thank you!